# How to disallow the selection of an interactive ListBox item?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, listbox

Some of the items in my ListBox use a template that contains a button and a TextBox. How can I make it such that it is impossible to select these items from the list, but still possible to interract with the button?

EDIT:

I still need to be able to select other items in this list, just not ones with this template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a attached property to the ListBoxItem (after I implemented I found [someone who had done almost the same](http://coderelief.net/2011/01/04/non-selectable-listboxitem-or-listviewitem-using-attached-properties/)) :

```
public class ListBoxItemEx
{
    public static bool GetCanSelect(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(CanSelectProperty);
    }
    public static void SetCanSelect(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(CanSelectProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CanSelectProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CanSelect", typeof(bool), typeof(ListBoxItemEx), new UIPropertyMetadata(true, OnCanSelectChanged));

    private static void OnCanSelectChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var item = sender as ListBoxItem;
        if (item == null)
            return;

        if ((bool)args.NewValue)
        {
            item.Selected -= ListBoxItemSelected;
        }
        else
        {
            item.Selected += ListBoxItemSelected;
            item.IsSelected = false;
        }
    }

    private static void ListBoxItemSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = sender as ListBoxItem;
        if (item == null)
            return;
        item.IsSelected = false;
    }
}
```

The xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="525"
    Height="350">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="local:ListBoxItemEx.CanSelect" Value="{Binding CanSelect}"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>     
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid Name="LayoutRoot">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemStyle}" SelectionMode="Multiple" />
</Grid>
```

The viewmodel:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged values

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion


    public List<Dummy> Elements { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        this.Elements = new List<Dummy>(){
            new Dummy() { CanSelect =true, MyProperty = "Element1"},
            new Dummy() { CanSelect =false, MyProperty = "Element2"},
            new Dummy() { CanSelect =true, MyProperty = "Element3"},
            new Dummy() { CanSelect =false, MyProperty = "Element4"},
            new Dummy() { CanSelect =true, MyProperty = "Element5"},
            new Dummy() { CanSelect =true, MyProperty = "Element6"},
            new Dummy() { CanSelect =true, MyProperty = "Element7"},
            new Dummy() { CanSelect =true, MyProperty = "Element8"},
            new Dummy() { CanSelect =false, MyProperty = "Element9"},
        };
    }
}

public class Dummy
{
    public bool CanSelect { get; set; }

    public string MyProperty { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.MyProperty;
    }
}
```

The only caveat with this approach is that trying to select an unselectable item unselects the current selected one if the ListBox has single selection, or unselects all, if the ListBox has extended selection.

Answer (score 1):

use [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) instead of ListBox

Comment: The other items in the list still need to be selectable. I have edited the question to make this more obvious.

Comment: I think no standard way to do that, you can try to keep in datacontext of each item if you want it to be selectable or not, and set listbox.SelectedItem = null if selected item is not selectable. Please let know if this work

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately this doesn't work form me because I have to check if the selected item is selectable after it has already been selected.