# Programmatically deselect a row in a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, selection, wpfdatagrid

I'm struggling to find a solution to this.

What I am trying to do is to only make certain rows selectable in a DataGrid. The SelectionMode is FullRow. An example would be if a user tried to drag-select a few rows, and one of them I wouldn't want to be selectable. In this instance I would want the valid rows to be selected still, but not the invalid one.

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you define an invalid row?

Comment: Items of a certain type would be invalid, so a typecheck would determine whether to allow the row to be selected or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This guy wanted to do something alike with a ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567794/how-to-disallow-the-selection-of-an-interactive-listbox-item/13588128#13588128). I believe the solution can be adapted to work with the DataGrid as well.

**EDIT**

```
public static class DataGridRowEx
{
    public static bool GetCanSelect(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(CanSelectProperty);
    }
    public static void SetCanSelect(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(CanSelectProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CanSelectProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CanSelect", typeof(bool), typeof(DataGridRowEx), new UIPropertyMetadata(true, OnCanSelectChanged));

    private static void OnCanSelectChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var item = sender as DataGridRow;
        if (item == null)
            return;

        if ((bool)args.NewValue)
        {
            item.Selected -= RowSelected;
        }
        else
        {
            item.Selected += RowSelected;
            item.IsSelected = false;
        }
    }

    private static void RowSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = sender as DataGridRow;
        if (item == null)
            return;

        item.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(()=>
        item.IsSelected = false));
    }
}
```

To test it:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged values

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion


    public List<Dummy> Elements { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        this.Elements = new List<Dummy>(){
            new Dummy() { CanSelect =true, MyProperty = "Element1"},
            new Dummy() { CanSelect =false, MyProperty = "Element2"},
            new Dummy() { CanSelect =true, MyProperty = "Element3"},
            new Dummy() { CanSelect =false, MyProperty = "Element4"},
            new Dummy() { CanSelect =true, MyProperty = "Element5"},
            new Dummy() { CanSelect =true, MyProperty = "Element6"},
            new Dummy() { CanSelect =true, MyProperty = "Element7"},
            new Dummy() { CanSelect =true, MyProperty = "Element8"},
            new Dummy() { CanSelect =false, MyProperty = "Element9"},
        };
    }
}

public class Dummy
{
    public bool CanSelect { get; set; }

    public string MyProperty { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.MyProperty;
    }
}

<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="525"
    Height="350"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="DataGridRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="local:DataGridRowEx.CanSelect" Value="{Binding CanSelect}" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}"
              RowStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridRowStyle}"
              SelectionUnit="FullRow" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

It works with multiselection, even when pressing shift. The only significant difference from the solution for the ListBoxItem was that the unselection had to be queued using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke, not sure why. 
The only caveat with this approach is that trying to select an unselectable item unselects the current selected one if the DataGrid has single selection, or unselects all, if the DataGrid  has extended selection.

Comment: Hmmm, I've tried it with my code but to no avail. However in the test project it works, so thanks. I'll try to integrate it with my code again.

Comment: I need to work out the logic for my specific application, but this has helped. the 

        item.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(()=>
        item.IsSelected = false));

lines were what I needed, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Not the best way to do this but you could make an inherted class that holds the selected index of the grid and then if an invalid row is selected you just change the selected index to the last valid index

Comment: Unfortunately, it needs to be able to work with multiple selection.

Comment: Same thing but with Selected Rows?

Comment: this is a dataGridView object right? yourgrid.SelectedRows

edit: just realised dataGrid is a separate thing, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Not a great solution but you could deselect the rows on a Mouse_Up event, so let the user select all then deselect programmatically, I have not tested this

```
private void dgvReport_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dgvReport.SelectedRows) {


                if (row.Cells[1].Value == "Invalid"){

                    this.dgvReport.Rows[row.Index].Selected = false;

                }


            }
        }
```

Comment: There is no Rows property.

Edit: Or SelectedRows.

Comment: @JamieKelly I assume you are using a DataGridView?

Answer (score 0):

This will work,

```
        int row = grdexam.SelectedIndex;
        DataGridRow rv =(DataGridRow)this.grdexam.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(row);
        DataRowView rvv =(DataRowView)rv.Item;
        MessageBox.Show(rvv.Row[1].ToString());
```